# Magento Delivery options

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

I want to be able to add three delivery options that have three different prices which change depending on the subtotal in the basket.

So here is an example -

```
Delivery Options name: UK

Shipping cost for orders under £200 = £5.00

Shipping cost for orders over £200 = £10.00

Shipping cost for orders over £400 = £15.00
```

I would like three of these setup which allows the user to ship to different locations. Te closest thing i can see to what i want to acheive is the 'table rates' but doesn't allow for multiple conditions.

I've done this before using an extention that allows us to add multiple flatrate delivery options but this isn't very clean from a users perspective.

Is there an extention that will allow this sort of thing? If possible at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your reply, however it looks like I was over looking what needed to be done. It can be done using the 'Table rate' shipping. All you need to do is upload a CSV of the shipping rules you would like to apply.

More info can be found here - http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/how-do-i-set-up-table-rate-shipping

Hope someone finds this handy..

Answer (score 0):

Josh you used,flat rate ,there need some modify in code...
Please check the details on the question...

[Flat Rate Shipping Based on Order Amount](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22456401/flat-rate-shipping-based-on-order-amount/2245786)

Comment: Thanks I'll take a look at the code and see if I can make sense of it.